# How too re-write some long urls to shprter urls

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, long-integer

ok, i've .htaccess at root of my site with -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /content/themes/MrOSX/pages/(.*).php [L]
```

Still i get 404 wh4en trying www.site.co/home.html

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the second `(.*)` by `$1` (The content of the first capturing parenthesis).

Comment: thanks. now the mrosx folder can be any namelk. how to capture.

Comment: Shouldn't this be another question ?